# how know value in the previous code in python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
v = ??
my_range = list(range(v))
print(sum(my_range, v) + pow(v, v, v))
```

I want to know to get value
output=820

Comment: You should consider the mathematics behind this based on your knowledge of how *range*, *sum* and *pow* work. The answer is **40** btw

Comment: i know how range work but this problem give me sum(range(v)) how i know value of v @DanielHao

Comment: i know it is 40 after i tried some random numbers if output is high value how i know v please clear me @AlbertWinestein

Comment: @MahmoudAboalwafa check my answer

Comment: Thans so much @AnikethMalyala

Comment: @MahmoudAboalwafa do you need any more help? (You haven’t accepted an answer so I’m not sure)

Comment: No thanks Every thing is ok @AnikethMalyala

Answer (score 2):

You could try a binary chop on an expected integer range:

```
def fn(v):
    my_range = list(range(int(v)))
    return sum(my_range, v) + pow(v, v, v)

a = 1
b = 100
r = 0

while True:
    v = (a + b) // 2
    r = fn(v)
    print(v, r)
    if r == 820:
        break
    elif r > 820:
        b = v
    else:
        a = v
```

Result:

```
50 1275
25 325
37 703
43 946
40 820
```

Comment: this is so extra and i love it

Comment: Clever. Very nice 

Answer (score 1):

This is basically math:

`my_range` = [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., v - 1]

`sum(my_range, v)` is the same as `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + v`.

`pow(v, v, v)` = `v^v % v` = `0`, since v * v * v * .... must be a multiple of v, so the mod will be 0.

Thus, we are solving for `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + v` = `820`

Using the summation formula (∑x from i=1 to n = n(n+1)/2 ):

v(v+1)/2 = 820 -> v(v+1) = 1640 -> v^2 + v - 1640 = 0

(v - 40)(v + 41) = 0

v = 40

Answer (score 0):

If N is the sum of a contiguous range of positive integers (from 1) then the highest number in that range can be expressed as the square root of N * 2 (rounded down to the nearest integer)

Therefore:

```
N = 820

print(int((N*2)**0.5))
```

**Output:**

```
40
```

**Note:**

The sum of a contiguous range of numbers (starting from 1) and ending at N can be calculated by:

```
(N * (N+1)) // 2
```

...hence the "reverse" approach shown here